# get value of time from database and show notification on that time

Tags: android, database, time, notifications

geting time from user and storing and retrive from database through this code but it show's notification of the last entered time from user

**MainActivity**

```
DBhelp dbHeleper= new DBhelp(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db=dbHeleper.getReadableDatabase();

String querString="select hours,minutes FROM Time";
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(querString, null);
hours=new String[cursor.getCount()]; 
minutes=new String[cursor.getCount()];

if(cursor.getCount()>0){
    int i=0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        hours[i]=cursor.getString(0);       
        minutes[i]=cursor.getString(1);
        i++;
    }
}

cursor.close();
db.close();
dbHeleper.close();

btnSaveNotification=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnSaveNotification.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ShowNotificationSetTime.this, MyReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ShowNotificationSetTime.this,1, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

hours get time formate like 14,15,16 and minutes 20,30,40

my broadcast receiving class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       context.startService(service1);  
    }
}
```

**service class..**

```
NotificationManager mManager =(NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DialogBoxNotification.class); 
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( getApplicationContext(),1, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);       
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"msg.", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),"title","msg", pendingNotificationIntent);

mManager.notify(1, notification);
mManager.notify(0, notification);
```